# how to avoid OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, performance, image-processing, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am trying to load 20 images in each Horizontal Listview. My RecyclerView Contains 7 horizontal Listview, each Listview contains 20 Images.When I click on any Listview for Image Details and Back press.while I m continue this step for 4 times then I get out of memory error.

How to avoid out of memory error?

Also can you suggest,

1. Which image loader is best for lots of Images load at a time without
   taking to much runtime memory.
2. Scaledown images of ListView containing High resolution Images.

Comment: I prefer Picasso or Glide for showing images

Comment: tried Picasso and Volley ImageLoader.but it still takes 72mb heap.

Comment: Are you sacaling the image to image view size in picasso. If not please do so.

Comment: any link for this ? @Nivedh

Comment: Go through http://square.github.io/picasso/   
And try to use .resize()
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)  may reduce your out of memory issue

Comment: Let me try.also one of the issue left,listview or recyclerview is better for lots of Images.?

Comment: Of course recycler view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about whether it help you or not, but please try this code

```
  @Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    System.gc(); // clear bitmap and other objects here to reduce memory. 
}
```

Comment: any other solutions there?